# pycrypto AES CBC

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I have written some code using the pycrypt library and I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is that I am doing wrong.  I can (nearly) decrypt messages with the wrong initialization vector even though I believe I am following their examples.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os
from string import ascii_letters

key, iv = os.urandom(32), os.urandom(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
plaintext = ascii_letters
plaintext += ' ' * (-len(plaintext) % 16)  # Padding
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, os.urandom(16))
text = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
# text[16:] = b'qrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ            '
```

Now aside from the first 16 bytes of the decrypted text, you have everything decrypted correctly with a totally random choice of IV.  Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal for cipher block chaining. In CBC decryption, the IV is only necessary to reconstruct the first block of plaintext. The computation of other blocks of plaintext doesn't actually involve the IV. Here's a diagram (source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CBC_decryption.svg) user WhiteTimberwolf, public domain):

[image: CBC decryption diagram]

Comment: So I guess I was misunderstanding the role of the IV.  It is only there to make it more difficult to unravel the encryption by adding additional mixing, but not to add any additional element of security beyond the secrecy of the key.  Thanks!

Comment: @Lars: The IV does improve security; attacks that would be possible if CBC did not have an IV are not possible due to the IV. However, it is not supposed to be a secret, and the fact that most of the plaintext can be recovered without the IV does not reduce the system's security.